# OneHot Encoding: Nan value - remove row or represent as a list full of zeros?

Tags: missing-data, categorical-encoding, data-imputation

In the analysis survey, I have responses without answers and I'm not sure what is a better approach. Most of the attributes are categorical and missing numerical attributes have to remove. What can I do with categorical attributes?

1)Drop all Nan rows and after that do one-hot encoding

2)Represent Nan value as a list of zeros. (Nan --> ..],[0,0,0,0],[..)

3)Something else

Each approach has probably advantages and disadvantages, what is better?

FYI: I can't fill that with mean/average value, due to preserving information.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the data after you code it? Simple statistical summaries and visualization, or something more complex?

Comment: Feature selection + predictive model based on this dataset.

Comment: The tags I've added should provide a starting point